# The general solution of the differential equation in a form of y'' = f(y')

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am seeking for the solutions of
$$y'' = f(y')$$
and
$$y'' = f(y)$$

Where  $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ is a real function of independent variable $x$

The hardest part for me is to understand, which substitutions are legitimate to apply here to not get wrong. So far, I considered 2 ways of solving first DE

1. In my professor's lectures I found the following idea. Let's use substitution $y' = t$. Then, $y'' = t'$ and then all the things come fairly straighforward
   $$t' = f(t) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{dt}{dx} = f(t) \Longleftrightarrow \int\frac{dt}{f(t)} = x + C, C \in \mathbb{R}$$
   Which is as far as I understand the general solution of the upper equation. Probably there may be more steps applied, but I don't know which exactly
2. Apparently, I found another way of solving this equation, using similar technique. First, let's rewrite original equation as $y'' = p(x)y'$ (I don't know the exact reasoning for such substitution and would be grateful, if you can explain). Then, as previously $y' = t$ and $y'' = t'$. As a result
   $$t' = p(x)t \Longleftrightarrow \frac{dt}{t} = p(x)dx \Longleftrightarrow ln(|t|) = \int p(x)dx + C, C \in \mathbb{R} $$
   $$\Longrightarrow t = C_{1}e^{\int p(x)dx}, C_{1} \in \mathbb{R}$$
   Then returning back to the substitution, we obtain
   $$\frac{dy}{dx} = C_{1}e^{\int p(x)dx} \Longleftrightarrow y = C_{1}\int{e^{\int p(x)dx}dx}$$
   Which is the general solution.

Of course, I like the second one more, but I cannot understand, where this substitution may come from. If you have any ideas on that, I would be very grateful if you share.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The second method is not a substitution, it is a solution method *if* the equation can be written in that particular form. In general, you will not be able to make that separation.

Comment: In what sense is the second method a solution? What is $p(x)$? What is the relation to $y''=f(y)$?

Comment: @ConMan do you have any ideas on how to generalize the method? I mean, that it may not work all the time, so, is there something that works always? And also, if it is not bothers you, can you please provide an example, when the method not works.

Comment: @Michael, it is solution in a way that you can put it into the original equation and it will satisfy it... I don't understand what is wrong with it. Also, I didn't mentioned, but both solutions were for the $y'' = f(y')$, because I don't know, how to solve $y'' = f(y)$ in general. Talking about the $p(x)$ term, I don't know too, I am here to find the truth whether I can use it or not. A friend of my said, that you can establish relation between $y''$ and $y'$ in such manner, but I wasn't sure about that reasoning, that's why I am here)

Comment: There is no general solution to $y'' = f(y)$, you will learn some approaches for specific cases in any course on Differential Equations.

Comment: Yeah, I know those, but the problem is to solve it generally. Probably, my professor just tried to fool me( But what about another one? Are there any approaches? What's wrong with $y'' = p(x)y'$ substitution?

Comment: Given $f(x)$, how do you choose $p(x)$?  How can you convert your "solution" into a solution?  For example suppose $f(x)=x^2$, for which the answer is $y'=\frac{1}{c-t}$. How do you choose $p(x)$ to get that answer? Are you claiming that any function $p(x)$ will give a valid solution?